# Can't see post votes by long tap in the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, vote-count

I can't see post votes by long tap on score on MSE via Android app. This is happened after my account was suspended.

On other sites this ability works as always.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (172342203b663)

Comment: Maybe caching? It can take some time to have everything restored after event like  suspension ends and account merges

Comment: @rene iOS app works fine in this case. So if it's really caching - it's Android app caching, not API. Will check later again.